# Impossible to import datetime field from xlsx file in odoo v16

Tags: datetime, import, xlsx, odoo-16

No matter what I have tried, I can't import a datetime field from an xlsx file in odoo 16.

I go to "Import records", then load an xlsx file and then I press test. I get the following error:   Column payment_date contains incorrect values. Error in line 204: unconverted data remains: 2022-11-21 09:34:46

I've tried with a variety of date time formats (including the one in language settings), but it always concludes to the above error message...

Which is the correct format to import a datetime field from an xlsx file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the source of the problem and solved it. For people who may encounter the same problem, in my case the problem was that the first rows of the excel file had an empty value for the datetime. When I sorted the excel to bring the rows with datetime values on top, it worked. So, the solution is to sort the excel file to bring first the entries with a value and leave the empty values at the end of the list.

Comment: You can acknowledge your question as solved.